# How to redirect a page to new window using codeigniter redirect function

Tags: codeigniter-2

i need make redirecting my content in new tab after some code checking.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('name') == FALSE) {
//...
Show form errors in some windows
//..
} else {
redirect("home/bill_print");
```

Please help.

Comment: consider to check the framework API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a server-side language (PHP) to control client-side behavior. You can Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript [`window.open`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript) function.